# Issue with std::stol - 'std::invalid_argument' what(): stol

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have an issue with `std::stol`. All answers I have found regarding to issues with `std::stol` or `std::stoi` are dealing with C++11 compiling / building.

```
std::string myString;
long myLong = std::stol(myString);
```

When I use `std::stol()` I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stol
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any ideas? Building with gcc -std::C++11 works fine.
Note: I think this is my first C++11 expression I use.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]

Comment: there is no number in `yourString` so what do you expect `yourLong` to be?

Comment: std::invalid_argument is thrown if no conversion could be performed.

Comment: Sorry that I my question / example was not clear. myString contains a number. @OzgurMurat I do not understand your comment.

Comment: @Nico see the exceptions section in the [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behaviour when your string does not contain a valid number that could be successfully converted to `long`.

To avoid the program being `terminate`d you could wrap your code in a [`try`...`catch` block](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions) and handle the exception.

Comment: Thank you, you made me check my vector of vectors again and the first line was invalid. Sorry that I asked but I could not find the mistake for my own for too long ;)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to  `try...catch` you can use `istringstream`.

```
std::string s; cin>>s;
std::istringstream iss(s);
long num;
if (!(iss >> num).fail()) {
     std::cout << num << std::endl;
     std::cout << std::stol(s) << std::endl; //safe
}
else {
      std::cerr << "Problem during conversion!" << std::endl;
}
```

`stol` should never cause any call to `terminate` if you first check if the string can be parsed to `long` using `istringstream`

[online example](https://ideone.com/XIVT8F)